# How to get status of form submission

Tags: php, forms, notifications, submit

I am looking for a "neat" (clean) way to show a status message after submitting a form.

For example, if a user updates their profile, I want to show a DIV with the text "Your Profile Has Been Updated!".

Right now I am getting this done this way:

After posting the data and either inserting or updating the database table, I do a header("Location: updateprofile.php?status=updated");

This works just fine and dandy, however it isn't very clean. I don't want the query string.

Another method I tried was to set a variable of $submitted=1; and not do a redirect after. However, when a user is updating their information it still shows the old information in the form fields until a refresh. So this doesn't work either.

I know I could use AJAX to submit the form and accomplish it that way, however, for what I am doing I do not want to use AJAX. I want a server side solution.

My only other thought is having to set a $_SESSION variable then somehow remove it after showing the status update.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: You can add something like `$_SESSION['notice']` and update it contents when it needed like `if(!empty($_SESSION['notice'])) { echo '<p class="notice">' . htmlentities($_SESSION['notice']) . '</p>'; unset($_SESSION['notice']); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time this is handled through session variables that store whatever flash messages need to be shown.

In a shared view (layout, element) put something like

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['flashMessage']) && !empty($_SESSION['flashMessage'])) {
        echo <<<EOF
        <div class="flashMessage">
            {$_SESSION['flashMessage']}
        </div>
EOF;
        unset($_SESSION['flashMessage']);
    }
?>
```

Set `$_SESSION['flashMessage']` to "Your profile has been updated." in whatever code is handling your form submissions.

Comment: You Rock! I knew there had to be something that could be done with SESSIONS I altered your code a bit by adding a second $_SESSION variable that states the message type (Success, Error, Warning, Info, Etc). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Quick note for others who might use this. It wasn't working on all my pages. I would set the session variables then do a header() redirect using Location:  Once the page loaded the session variables would be empty. The solution is to add die() or exit() right after the header() redirect. This will set the SESSION variables before moving on. I got this solutions from http://netweblogic.com/php/session-variables-not-set-header/

Answer (score 0):

Store the statuses in a session array variable, then simply do:

```
<?php 

if ( !empty( $_SESSION['statuses'] ) ) {

  foreach ( $_SESSION['statuses'] as $status ) {

    // Wrap in tags and format as needed
    echo $status;  

  }

  $_SESSION['statuses'] = Array();

}
```